# Twig - replace string case insensitive

Tags: replace, twig, case-insensitive

I want to replace a text inside string using twig to make it bold, here's my code:

```
{{ string|replace({(text): '<span style="font-weight: bold;">'~text~'</span>'})|raw }}
```

In this example:

```
string = "Hello world!"
text = "hello"
```

Will not replace the word 'Hello'. How can I make it to be case insensitive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the `replace` filter is case sensitive and there are no option to change it.

If you look at Twig's source code, you can see that `replace` uses `strtr`:

```
// lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php
(...)
new Twig_SimpleFilter('replace', 'strtr'),
```

If you don't care to loose your original case, you can use workarounds, such as:

```
{{ string|lower|replace({(text): '<span style="font-weight: bold;">'~text~'</span>'})|raw }}
```

See: http://twigfiddle.com/6ian2b

Else, you can create your own extension, something like:

```
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('ireplace', function($input, array $replace) {
  return str_ireplace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $input);
});
```

I think that this feature might be useful for the whole Twig community, you can open an enhancement on [GitHub](https://github.com/twigphp/twig/issues).