# Replace function inside value not working

Tags: replace, twig

Maybe I'm doing it wrong (tried several ways to achieve my goal) or overlooking something here.
What I'd like to achieve is this:

When I use the Live-search function, I get categories containing the search keyword (like: Paint -> Paint buckets, Paint brushes, Paint colors etc.) which works like a charm. The one thing I need is to style the searched keyword in the presented categories like:

**Paint** bucket,
**Paint** brushes,
Color **paint**

**This is the code I have at the moment:**

```
{% if (products.length + categories.length + pages.length) == 0 %} 
<div id="Pi56dYpB" class="undefined"> No results for: 
    <b>{{ query }}</b>...
</div>
{% endif %}

{% if categories.length > 0 %}
<div class="categories">
    
    {% for category in categories %}
        {% if loop.index < 7 %} 
            <a class="p-0" href="{{ category.url }}" style="all:inherit;">
                <h3 id="bvwiyjEN" class="undefined">{{ category.name|replace({{ query }}: "<strong>"{{ query }}"<strong>"})|raw }}</h3>
            </a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

Unfortunately this isn't working. I did check if the {{ query }} value is accessible with this simple line of code:

```
<h3 id="bvwiyjEN" class="undefined">{{ category.name }} - {{ query }}</h3>
```

No problems found here.

Did I use the wrong syntax in my code maybe? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does `{{ query }}` actually output then?

Comment: FYI:  `{% for category in categories|slice(0,7) %}` would be a lot more efficient.

Comment: @DarkBee {{ query }} is the given search keyword. Like Paint

Comment: @DarkBee "{% for category in categories|slice(0,7) %}" Does this mean that I could remove the {% if loop.index < 7 .. ? If I do, I get empty results.

Comment: Will only work if `categories` is an actual array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace({{ query }})` is the wrong syntax - `replace(query)` should work, as you don't want to echo the variable `query` here

Comment: While this is correct, I doubt it will work as `query` should be of the type `traversable` (which I assume it's not cause OP just puts `<b>{{query}}</b>` in the code)

Comment: Can you share more details? Which parts of the given code make you think that `query` is not a string?

Comment: @DarkBee I tried your solutions, but the output is empty, without errors. Even when I scale it down to: {{ category.name|replace({ (query) : "test"}) }} It turns out empty. I'm very glad you take the time helping me out here! The same for all other members!

Comment: @Hielke check the [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/bukmy1). Should work, also you should really enable debug mode in twig

Comment: @DarkBee The platform is totally closed source, without any possibility to change settings unfortunately :-(

Comment: @DarkBee I copied your example right into the code, but the same result: Empty H3 tag

Answer (score -1):

As [Nico Haase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71348672/replace-function-inside-value-not-working/71348704#71348704) pointed out already, `{{ ... }}` is used to output variables, this translate to something like `<?php echo $foo; ?>` and can't/shouldn't be used inside statements

Furthermore, the filter `replace` expects an array of `keys` to replace with the `values`.

You would need to change your code to the following:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category|replace({ (query): '<strong>'~query~'</strong>',})|raw }}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/bukmy1)

---

Some notes:

- The filter `replace` uses the `PHP` function [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) in the background. This mean the output will be case-sensitive. If you don't want this, I'd advice you to follow through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720043/twig-replace-string-case-insensitive)
- Wrapping the key with parantheses is mandatory. This will force twig to evaluate/interpolate the value of the `key` - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/owmk9d)